# Setting tweepy useragent universally?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I've been playing with tweepy for a while, but I keep having rate-limiting issues, getting 429 errors. I know you can set the headers on individual calls like

```
api.get_user('twitter', headers={'User-Agent': 'MyUserAgent'})
```

but is there a way to set the header in one place and not have to do it on every api call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hacky way:

```
import functools
class NewAPI(object):
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        call = getattr(self.api, key)
        @functools.wraps(call)
        def wrapped_call(*args, **kwargs):
            headers = kwargs.pop('headers', {})
            headers['User-Agent'] = 'MyUserAgent' # or make this a class variable/instance variable
            kwargs['headers'] = headers
            return call(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped_call

api = NewAPI(api)
print(api.get_user('twitter'))
```

Disclaimer: untested as I don't have tweepy.

Comment: sorry it took a while to get back to you... I'm testing it now, but twitter's rate-limiting it... Do you know of any good `functools` tutorials? I just want to understand this a little better

Comment: `functools` isn't the important thing here. What I'm doing there is wrapping the original call; `functools.wraps` is just a nice utility that makes the wrapped function look a bit more like the original.